# How to add text to video (imprint) programmatically in WindowsPhone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, video, text

I need to programmatically imprint some text on top of a video, at recording time. Do we have some like WriteableBitmap, but for videos ?

Comment: What language are you coding in? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: C#. No, i don't have any piece of code. I want to code an app and just wondering if this is possible, I want the user to record a video and have the choice to imprint some free text as explanations (eq title - "My trip to Zoo") and / or static or variable information (eq "Recording Start Date/Time" (static) or Elapsed Time (variable)). And this imprints most be on every video frame.

Comment: And user must set the text BEFORE recording begin